# Использование typename при обращении к вложенным классам в шаблонном коде

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пример:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// 1
void foo()
{
    struct A { struct B {}; };
    static_assert(std::is_class_v<A>);
    static_assert(std::is_class_v<A::B>);
}

// 2
template<typename... Ts>
void boo()
{
    struct A { struct B {}; };
    static_assert(std::is_class_v<A>);
    static_assert(std::is_class_v<A::B>); // Ошибка компиляции - требуется добавить typename.
}

int main()
{
    boo<int>();
}
```

В нешаблонном коде я могу обратиться к вложенному классу, определенному в локальном классе, без `typename`, а в шаблонном это приводит к ошибке компиляции.

Подскажите, где в стандарте регламентируется данное поведение? Почему в данном случае имя вложенного класса (`B`) становится *зависимым*?

Comment: Какой компилятор? У меня только кланг ругается.

Comment: Вот сюда надо смотреть: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#expr

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, пробовал с gcc 13 и clang 16.

Comment: Ясно. Добавил вызов второй функции, воспроизвелось на всех трех. Тогда тянет на дефект в стандарте.

Comment: Ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77302163/6266408